# How to convert number into decimal with shifted decimal separator?

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers, file-import

I have to import a file that have an amount in the following format:

```
Id    Amount
101   123456 
102   456789
```

I'm using `FileHelpers` library with `[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal)]` attribute but it converts the amount into this:

```
12356 --> $123456
```

I want it to apply last two digits to the decimals. I want it to look like this:

```
123456 --> $1234.56
456789 --> $4567.89
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I came up with my own solution. I've created a separate field called `Amount` that calculates the payment amount based on the the amount provided in file, which is parsed into the private variable called `AmountRaw`.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class PaymentFileRecord
{
    public int PaymentId;

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyyMMdd")]
    public DateTime PaymentDate;

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal)]
    private decimal AmountRaw;

    public decimal Amount
    {
        get { return AmountRaw / 100; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: divide the number you receive by 100.

Comment: Thanks, John. I edited the question with my solution.